# Получить индекс массива из дат

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Задача такая, дан массив, состоящий из одних дат. Хочу получить индекс через значение,  но какой элемент я бы не выбрал, всегда получаю -1.

```js
var k = [
  new Date('2017-07-17'),
  new Date('2017-07-20'),
  new Date('2017-07-23'),
  new Date('2017-07-26'),
  new Date('2017-07-28'),
  new Date('2017-07-30')
]

console.log(k.indexOf(new Date('2017-07-28')));
```

Comment: Храните даты строками, а к объекту приводите когда нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычный `indexOf` не сработает, так как у нас даты в виде обьектов, но можно использовать метод `findIndex` ([подробней о нем](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)) например с приведением даты к числу.

То-есть мы передаем в `findIndex` метод сравнения, который приводит 2ве даты в числа и сравнивает их :

```js
var k = [
  new Date('2017-07-17'),
  new Date('2017-07-20'),
  new Date('2017-07-23'),
  new Date('2017-07-26'),
  new Date('2017-07-28'),
  new Date('2017-07-30')
];

var testDate = new Date('2017-07-28');
var index = k.findIndex(i => +i == +testDate);

console.log(index);
```

ПС: прям в документации (ссылка выше) есть полифилл на данный метод, если нужна поддержка более старых браузеров.

Comment: Благодарю за скорый ответ!

Comment: @Михаил если ответ помог, отметьте вопрос как решенный, чтобы он мог быть полезным и другим.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @Михаил там возле ответа слева должно быть что-то типа галочки

Comment: Хоть глаз выколи, я не нашел.

Comment: @Михаил там где стрелочки (голоса за ответ) должно быть, наверное :)

Comment: Спасибо, наконец-то нашел :)